# How to avoid a double-up of effort for retina, when using tile maps from Tiled with Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, tmx

I've got retina tile maps working, 15x10 tiles, of 64x64 tiles. problem is for non-retina devices I will need to make a 15x10 tiles of 32x32 tiles. I don't want to recreate the Tile, is it just a case of changing the XML (.tmx) file? Is there an automated tool or another way around this? I've been looking online but not getting too much help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to update the TMX file and scale certain attributes. Unless your TMX map is very simple this will be a tedious and error-prone task that's best left to a tool.

There are a variety of TMX rescaling tools out there, but some didn't work for me or simply were incomplete at the time (ie one didn't scale object layers). All the tools I know are generally are written in rather unusual languages (for an iOS developer at least) like Python, Ruby or Bash scripts. Others are only available as binary without the source code.

[Check out this cocos2d forum post](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11660). Specifically [this tool](http://wasabibit.com/WasabiBit/Dev_Notes.html) or [HDx on the App Store](http://www.sovapps.com/hd2x/). [iTilemaps](http://www.klemix.com/page/iTileMaps.aspx) might also work for you.

Because I wasn't happy with either of the choices, I wrote my own command line tool **tmx2scale** in Objective-C to rescale TMX maps intelligently in all directions. The tmx2scale tool is not currently available but it will be distributed complete with source code with the [KoboldScript Game Kit project](http://www.koboldscript.com/).