# Tilemap is not filling up entire scene

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, scene

I'm using cocos2d with a viewcontroller in Xcode 5. I create a CCDirector as a child viewcontroller, and then add this to a UIView that is in the storyboard.

myViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CCDirector* director = (CCDirector *)[self childViewControllers][0];
    director.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 176);
    [_sceneView addSubview:[director view]];
}
```

The tilemap is created in IntroLayer.m.

```
-(id) initWithViewContoller:(MyCocosViewController *)viewController
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

    _tileMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"apartmentWithWall.tmx"];
    [self addChild:_tileMap z:-1];
    _tileMap.scale = 1;

    _bgLayer = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Floorplan"];
    self.wall = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Walls"];
    _wall.visible = NO;
}
```

And the scene is made in IntroLayer.m also

```
+(CCScene *) sceneWithViewController:(MyCocosViewController *)viewController
{

    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];


    IntroLayer *layer = [[IntroLayer node] initWithViewContoller:viewController];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];


    return scene;
}
```

This code successfully creates the tilemap and puts it into the view. However, the tilemap does not take up the whole scene - it seems to be only half sized. It is placed on the bottom left of the view, and the rest of the view is just black. If you touch on it, then the pixels are not scaled correctly - you can touch on the black part, and it still thinks this is part of the tilemap. This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzIFK.png

The white and black floorplan on the bottom left should take up the entire scene.

So why isn't it just naturally scaled correctly? The tutorials I've looked at don't seem to have this problem.

Comment: on retina devices you have to have a -hd tmx and -hd tileset

Comment: how do I do this?? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: found it ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060750/how-to-avoid-a-double-up-of-effort-for-retina-when-using-tile-maps-from-tiled-w

Comment: I used the app from the App store that you linked to, and made an hd tile map.. but now it's half the size it was before! So it's a quarter of the size it should be. This is killing me...